# Hibernate Many-to-One mapping with not null constraint

Tags: hibernate, constraints, many-to-one, notnull

I have a many-to-one mapping and not null constraint on the column. i am getting the exception column is Null while saving. Can anybody please suggest how do i use cascade and inverse in this scenario?

Comment: Show us your mapping, and the code you use to save, and we'll tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `@NotNull`, indicate that the association is not optional using `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`. The `@NotNull` is not specific to Hibernate; it's a generic bean annotation that may be enforced prior to saving the entitites. To be safe, I suggest using `@NotNull` primarily for `@Column` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

the entity with the onetomany/collection will by default maintain the association by cascading to the child which inserts first without the backreference and then updates the id. To solve this the onetomany/collection mapping must have the inverse attribute set and the backreference in the child must be set correctly.